# "Insert or update" in function - unique key violation - transaction issue?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, postgresql-9.2

I have PostgreSQL function which is used for counting usage of "items" by users. 
Counter values are saved into table:

**users_items**

```
user_id - integer (fk)
item_id - integer (fk)
counter - integer
```

There is max. 1 counter per user per item (unique key).

Here is my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION increment_favorite_user_item (item integer, userid integer) RETURNS integer AS 
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        new_count  integer;   -- Usage counter
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM users_items WHERE user_id = userid AND item_id = itemid) 
        THEN
            INSERT INTO users_items ("user_id", "item_id", "counter") VALUES (userid, itemid, 1); -- First usage - create new counter
            new_amount = 1;
        ELSE
            UPDATE users_items SET count = count + 1 WHERE (user_id = userid AND item_id = itemid); -- Increment counter
            SELECT counter INTO new_count FROM users_items WHERE (user_id = userid AND item_id = itemid);
        END IF;

        RETURN new_count;
    END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
VOLATILE;
```

It is used by application, which may call it multiple times.
Everything works fine until we call the function one after another, for the same user and item, when the item is new for specific user (record in users_items table does not exist).

For second function call, I get unique violation: "Key (user_id, item_id)=(1, 7912) already exists".
It seems like "if not exists" check doesn't work properly, second function call doesn't see record inserted by first one, and tries to insert same row, making the uq check fail.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Every function call runs in another transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a) race condition, b) you should to LOCK table if you would to ensure INSERT

```
DECLARE rc int;
BEGIN
  LOCK TABLE users IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
  UPDATE users SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE user_id = $1;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
  IF rc = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO users(id, counter) VALUES($1, 1)
  END IF;
END;
```

or more complex code, but with less locking

```
DECLARE rc int;
BEGIN
  -- fast path
  UPDATE users SET counter  = counter + 1 WHERE user_id = $1;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
  IF rc = 0 THEN
    LOCK TABLE users IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;
    UPDATE users SET counter  = counter + 1 WHERE user_id = $1;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS rc = ROW_COUNT;
    IF rc = 0 THEN
      INSERT INTO users(id, counter) VALUES($1, 1)
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer, I'll test it tomorrow morning. :)